# Should goroutine/channel-based mechanism replace a concurrent map?

Tags: go

There's a `map[PlayerId]Player` to check whether player is online and perform state alterations knowing his ID. This must be done from multiple goroutines concurrently.

For now I plan to use [streamrail's concurrent map](https://github.com/streamrail/concurrent-map*), but what about a regular map and synchronization using channels?

- Should it always be preferred in Go?
- Should it be preferred in certain circumstances?
- Are they basically just two ways to accomplish the same thing?

BTW, I know the slogan:

> don't communicate by sharing memory share memory by communicating

but there are locking mechanisms in stdlib and no words in docs about not using them at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the simplest approach: a map and RWMutex.

I cannot recommend using concurrency library unless it is widely used and tested (see https://github.com/streamrail/concurrent-map/issues/6 for example).

Note that even if you use github.com/streamrail/concurrent-map you will still need to implement your own synhronisation (use RWMutex) in the following scenario:

```
if _, ok = m[k]; !ok {
   m[k] = newPlayer()
}
```

If your game is super popular and played by many players you will find that this  approach doesn't scale but I would worry about it only if it becomes a problem.

Comment: The map implementation that I've mentioned does exactly the same - a regular map with a RWMutex. But what can you say about channels vs. thread-safe containers in general? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: The map implementations you mentioned tries to be more scalable by splitting the keys into multiple shards and using a single RWMutex per shard. It is not very clear if the goal has been achieved though, there are no benchmarks showing that it scales better under concurrent access.

Comment: channels, locks, atomic variables, thread-safe collections are just tools to achieve your goals. There are use cases for all of them, depending on your requirements. And remember that sometimes a single-threaded program is the fastest ;)

Comment: Thank you for your time, you're being very helpful, and I indeed should pay more attention to the code I show people :) but can you please in sake of additional clarification highlight a few cases where channels are at their best?

Comment: Read for example https://blog.golang.org/pipelines, http://talks.golang.org/2012/concurrency.slide#1, http://blog.golang.org/advanced-go-concurrency-patterns